# jquery upload doesn't work in ie9

Tags: jquery, html, upload

Hi i have a small problem can you help me please

html part

```
<input type="file" id="browse" name="browse" size=""  placeholder="Photo" checked="checked" class="upload"/>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:onbrowse()"  class="unknown" value="test"/>
<div class="qaq"></div>
```

css part

```
.unknown, .qaq, .qaq img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

script part

```
$(".upload").change(function () {
    var fileObj = this,
        file;

    if (fileObj.files) {
        file = fileObj.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader;
        fr.onloadend = changeimg;
        fr.readAsDataURL(file)
    } else {
        file = fileObj.value;
        changeimg(file);
    }
});

function onbrowse() {
    document.getElementById('browse').click();
}

function changeimg(str) {
    if(typeof str === "object") {
        str = str.target.result; // file reader
    }

    $(".unknown").css({"background-size":  "100px 100px",
                       "background-image": "url(" + str + ")"});
    $( ".qaq" ).append( "<img src='"+str+"' />" );
}
```

jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/wU3Vu/

in ie9 in doesn't show picture if you add some picture to upload.

but in other browsers it work fine... please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fileObj.value` returns file system path. It can't be set to src attribute of image.

More details:
In other browsers it works because they support HTML5 FileAPI feature http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi. As you can see IE9 does not support this and can't access file on client side.